# How to set 404 Response Code according to condition in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to set http response code according to condition in php page.

```
if($Variable== true)
{
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found", true, 404);           
    include('404.php');
    die();
}
```

I am looking something like below.

```
 if($Variable == true)
      // http response code =404
   else
     // http response code =200
```

Is it possible to do this thing in php?

I have tried as below to solve it. But not worked.

```
if($Variable ==true)
{
    http_response_code(404);
    include('404.php');
   die();
}
```

Comment: `http_response_code(404);`

Comment: Tried but getting 200 response code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php `http_response_code()` which Get or Set the HTTP response code.

```
<?php

if($Variable == true)
      // http response code =404
    http_response_code(404));
   else
    http_response_code(200))
     // http response code =200
```

Comment: Tried but getting 200 response code.

Comment: then something wrong with your condition @BhaveshPatel

Comment: Checked condition but response code is shown wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. it might help you.

```
   <?php
   if($Variable == true)
     header("Status: 404 Not Found");
   else
     header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? One of both formats is not the proper one